# Execution failed for task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a] in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: android, react-native, jenkins, expo

I am fairly new to expo and i took over a mobile app project which started as a native app and then expo and RN was integrated on top of it. I am building a Jenkins pipeline and i've been stuck with this issue for more than one week now. The build fails with this error:

Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.

- Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Unfortunately this is all i got, i tried to remove the env variable by calling "unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" before starting the build but it's not working at all. The build is running successfully on my local device (m1 mac) but it doesn't on the pipeline. I'm using jenkins to run a docker container and run the build from there.

Here's the result of expo-env-info:

```
OS: Linux 5.10 Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 11 (bullseye) 
Shell: 5.1.4 - /bin/bash 12:53:34      
Binaries: 12:53:34        
Node: 17.9.0 - ~usr/bin/node 12:53:34        
Yarn: 3.4.1 - ~usr/bin/yarn 12:53:34        
npm: 8.5.5 - ~usr/bin/npm 12:53:34      
npmPackages: 12:53:34       
u/expo/metro-config: ^0.10.7 => 0.10.7  12:53:34        
expo: 49.0.10 => 49.0.10  12:53:34        
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0  12:53:34        
react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0  12:53:34        
react-native: 0.72.4 => 0.72.4  12:53:34      
Expo Workflow: managed
```

If someone has any clue of what should i do, it will be greatly appreciated, as i'm becoming quite desperate.

Cheers

Comment: hi there! This error usually occurs when the CMake version on your Jenkins server is not compatible with the version required by the expo-modules-core package.